# Java dir/files list

Tags: java, file, dir

I am trying to list all directories and files within a certain directory, but while "D:\data" works, "D:\" doesn't. *"D"* is a secondary disk.

This is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
    at project.1.scavenger.listf(scavenger.java:19)
    at project.1.scavenger.listf(scavenger.java:30)
    at project.1.scavenger.listf(scavenger.java:30)
    at project.1.main(Project1.java:28)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Code:

```
public static List<File> listf(String directoryName) throws IOException {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<File>();

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                System.out.println(scavenger.checkmime(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            resultList.addAll(listf(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
    // System.out.println(fList);
    return resultList;
}

public static String checkmime(String fl) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    File file = new File(fl);
    String mimeType = file.toURL().openConnection().getContentType();
    // System.out.println(mimeType);
    return mimeType;
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Which line is this: `at project.1.scavenger.listf(scavenger.java:19)`?

Comment: File#listFiles will return null when the abstract path doesn't exist or can't be read (ie a shortcut)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Do you write for the dir "D:\" or "D:\\"? Backslashes should be escaped.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I guess Mac OS X, because Mac OS X is the only OS which uses drive letters, right? :P

Comment: And by the way, have a look here, if you want a faster solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920479/why-does-the-java-directorystream-perform-so-slow/30920911?noredirect=1#comment49882496_30920911 Use it with [probeContent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: @tom There is a difference in security models between windows 7 and windows 8 which may account for the inability to list the root drive

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, yes, that might be true. Your question sounds more like "do you use Linux, Mac or Windows" instead of "Which version of Windows" (at least to me). Then, sorry for that comment :).

Comment: @tom If they were using Unix, that would have at least explained something :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Removed error from your version

In your recursion you never ask for null values. Do it and it should run like this:

```
  public static List<File> listf(String directoryName) throws IOException {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    // this was missing
    if (fList == null) {
      return null;
    }
    resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
    for (File file : fList) {
      if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
          System.out.println(checkmime(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
      } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        // ask here if it was null
        List<File> files = listf(file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (files != null) {
          resultList.addAll(files);
        }
      }
    }
    //System.out.println(fList);
    return resultList;
  }
```

### Why D:\data works and D:\ not

In every root of a drive in a Windows System is a hidden folder structure called $RECYCLE.BIN. In this folder windows stores for each user (sid) an own folder with deleted data (links to it). But a normal user is only allowed to get the first level and not the user folder (with sid value as name).

(German Windows: Papierkorb = Trash)

[image]

### A maybe much better solution:

A maybe better way of doing such searchings in tree's is to create an Iterator over the directory tree (like a composite iterator). This solution also uses only Java NIO features, so the platform should be changeable (haven't tested!) to for ex. Linux.

#### DirectoryTreeIterator.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DirectoryTreeIterator implements Iterator<Path> {

  private final Deque<Iterator<Path>> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();

  public DirectoryTreeIterator(Iterator<Path> it) {
    deque.push(it);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    if (deque.isEmpty()) {
      return false;
    } else {
      Iterator<Path> it = deque.peek();
      if (!it.hasNext()) {
        deque.pop();
        return hasNext();
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Path next() {
    if (hasNext()) {
      Iterator<Path> it = deque.peek();
      Path p = it.next();
      try {
        // here is the magic recursive on only filtered paths
        if (Files.isDirectory(p) && Files.isReadable(p) && !Files.isHidden(p)) {
          deque.push(Files.newDirectoryStream(p).iterator());
        }
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
      }
      return p;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Then you are able to use it like a charm:

#### FileLister.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class FileLister {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get("D:\\");

    Iterator<Path> it = Files.newDirectoryStream(p).iterator();
    DirectoryTreeIterator dti = new DirectoryTreeIterator(it);
    while (dti.hasNext()) {
      Path path = dti.next();
      if (!Files.isDirectory(path)) {
        String mime = Files.probeContentType(path);
        System.out.println("Mime of File "
                + path.getFileName() + " is: " + mime);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But why? What's the difernce between d:\ and d:\data? Why can't the op scan the root directory?

Comment: Made an Update to show how you iterate over an Directory Tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you add this code right beneath the `directory.listFiles()` call:

```
if (fList == null) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't read files in directory: " + directoryName);
    return resultList;
}
```

then you will get a message like this:

> Couldn't read files in directory: G:\$RECYCLE.BIN\*Windows SID*

This *Windows SID*s is [security identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) for a user on your local machine.
So that means your current user has no permission to read this directory (it belongs to a different user) in the "recycle bin" directory, therefore `listFiles()` returns `null` instead of a `String[]`.

You could keep the check and the message I've posted, or you can implement a different way to handle "unreadable" directories.

About why `"D:\\"` failed and `"D:\\data"` not:

- `"D:\\"` contains the mentioned *"$RECYCLE.BIN"* directory with restricted access
- `"D:\\data"` has no directory where your current user isn't allowed to access/read it, therefore `listFiles()` never returned `null`.