# How do I revert this Lambda Expression?

Tags: lambda, java-8

I want to revert these Lambda Expressions:

```
PathInfo::new
p ->   p.getFileName()
```

While keeping the same performance discussed in the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920479/why-does-the-java-directorystream-perform-so-slow). Here's the original method:

```
public List<String> getSortedFile(Path dir) 
  throws IOException 
{
    return Files.list(dir).map(PathInfo::new).sorted()
        .map(p -> p.getFileName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'd like to revert them similar to [how Javin Paul did it in this article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/02/10-example-of-lambda-expressions-in-java8.html):

```
// Before Java 8: 
JButton show = new JButton("Show"); 
show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{ 
  @Override 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  { 
    System.out.println("Event handling without lambda expression is boring"); 
  } 
}); 

// Java 8 way: 
show.addActionListener((e) -> { 
  System.out.println("Light, Camera, Action !! Lambda expressions Rocks"); 
});
```

And here's the best solution discussed from the source:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileSorter {

    public List<String> getSortedFile(Path dir) throws IOException {
        return Files.list(dir).map(PathInfo::new).sorted().map(p -> p.getFileName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static class PathInfo implements Comparable<PathInfo> {
        private final String fileName;
        private final long modified;
        private final long size;

        public PathInfo(Path path) {
          try {
            // read the whole attributes once
            BasicFileAttributes bfa = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
            fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
            modified = bfa.lastModifiedTime().toMillis();
            size = bfa.size();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(PathInfo o) {
            int cmp = Long.compare(modified, o.modified);
            if (cmp == 0)
                cmp = Long.compare(size, o.size);
            return cmp;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // File (io package)
        File f = new File("C:\\Windows\\system32");
        // Path (nio package)
        Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\Windows\\system32");

        FileSorter fs = new FileSorter();

        long before4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<String> names4 = fs.getSortedFile(dir);
        long after4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Run time of Stream.sorted as List with caching: " + ((after4 - before4)));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "revert them"?

Comment: Basically don't use Lambda Expressions so that I can use Javassist 3.18.1-GA instead of updating to version 3.18.2-GA and/or updating hibernate. The error I'm getting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313255/reflections-java-8-invalid-constant-type

Comment: If you must avoid lambda expressions, why bother with streams API at all?  Do this the regular java 7 way.  Make a `List<PathInfo>`, sort it using `Collections.sort` and then make a list of filenames.

Comment: Because I'm working with a bulky system that needs to be faster due to my requirements. If I can't use stream APIs and not Lambda Expressions then I'll cut down on time elsewhere.

Comment: Why? Have you actually measured this?

Comment: Why what? Have I measured what? I haven't measured anything, I'm assuming the folks in the "source" link I posted above are providing accurate times.

Comment: So you're asking how to convert a lambda expression to an anonymous inner class? Just ask your IDE to do it.

Comment: I didn't know my IDE could do that until Tagir posted his answer. I simply Import my group's Eclipse-Luna code formatter configuration xml sheets then am told to never edit those configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert all lambdas to anonymous classes you may use the IDE features. Most modern Java IDEs support this. For example, in Eclipse right-click on the project, navigate to

Source -> Clean Up -> Use custom profile -> Configure... -> Code Style -> Functional interface instances -> [x] Convert functional interface instances -> [x] Use anonymous class:

[image: Eclipse Source Clean Up]

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't know Eclipse could do that. Thank you! =)

Comment: Really helpful. But unfortunately, doesn't support in new Eclipse IDE