# What's the right way to check null or check exceptions in a chained statement in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, java-8, java-stream

For example for this code:

```
List<Class> classes = 
        Stream.of("java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.String")
              .map(className -> Class.forName(className))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This code runs fine now. but, assume we have a empty list in stream and we have tons of operations to the stream. It could get NullPointer exceptions and etc.
I find it's also hard to try-catch for this kind of statement.
What's the right way to handle exception for this?

Comment: What? If it's empty, nothing will be applied. Try catch? Where? Why?

Comment: what do you mean "empty list in stream"? Your Stream is of String, not List. Did you mean "null string in stream"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to check for nulls. If you have an empty stream  all operations will be skipped:

```
Stream.of("hello")
      .filter(e => "world".equals(e)) // empties the stream
      .foreach(System.out::println); // no NullPointer, no output
```

Exception handling is possible in mapper:

```
    List<Class<?>> classes = Stream.of("java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.String")
            .map(className -> {
                try {
                    return Class.forName(className);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new YourRuntimeException();
                }
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want exceptions to be ignored, then I suggest to map to `Optional`s.

```
    List<Class<?>> classes = Stream.of("java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.String")
            .map(className -> {
                try {
                    return Optional.of(Class.forName(className));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return Optional.<Class<?>>empty();
                }
            })
            .filter(Optional::isPresent) // ignore empty values
            .map (Optional::get) // unwrap Optional contents
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please also have a look at [How can I throw CHECKED exceptions from inside Java 8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644361/how-can-i-throw-checked-exceptions-from-inside-java-8-streams?rq=1) for a more detailed discussion about `Class.forName` in combination with java 8 streams.

Comment: Neither is `=>`. Note that the three steps, mapping to `Optional`, filtering via `Optional.isPresent`, and unwrapping the `Optional` are unnecessarily complicated. A single `flatMap` can do the operation.

Comment: `filter` and `map` in your last example could be replaced by `flatMap(Optional::stream)` (if Java >= 9).

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit strange. You are claiming “This code runs fine now” whereas it should generate compile-time errors as you are not handling the checked exception declared by `Class.forName`. Further you are talking about empty lists, but in your code, no lists are involved. The same applies to your reference to `NullPointerException` as your code does not produce `null` at any place.

Most probably, you are talking about a code which catches the `ClassNotFoundException` and handles it by returning `null`. You should never do this. If you want to filter out failures, you may do it this way:

```
List<Class<?>> classes = 
    Stream.of("java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.String")
        .flatMap(className -> {
                try {
                    return Stream.of(Class.forName(className));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    // recommended: insert logging statement here
                    return Stream.empty();
                }
            })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way, no element will be generated in the case of an exception and you don’t have to do additional error handling downstream.

Answer (score 0):

We can use try-with-resources also,

```
try(List<Class> classes = Stream.of("java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.String"))
{
 List<Class> classes = Stream.of("java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.String")        
              .map(className -> Class.forName(className))
              .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

should add `throws Exception` to handle

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure what you meant by "have a empty list in stream", but if you wanted to safely handle possibility of nulls in the Stream, you could use:

```
List<Class> classes =
Stream.of("java.lang.Object", "java.lang.Integer", "java.lang.String", null)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(className -> {
      try {
        return Class.forName(className);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No class found for: " + className);
        return null;
      }
    })
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```