# Handling exception in the lambda without try-catch in the lambda

Tags: java, lambda, exception, java-8

As far as I know, one could not handle exception thrown in the lambda if the abstract method implemented by the lambda doesn't have `throws` in its signature.

I encountered following code, it works. Why `openStream()` doesn't demand handling `IOException`? I can see `try-catch` in the `tryWithResources` but I don't understand the mechanism behind it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {

    public static <AUTOCLOSEABLE extends AutoCloseable, OUTPUT> Supplier<OUTPUT> tryWithResources(
            Callable<AUTOCLOSEABLE> callable, Function<AUTOCLOSEABLE, Supplier<OUTPUT>> function,
            Supplier<OUTPUT> defaultSupplier) {
        return () -> {
            try (AUTOCLOSEABLE autoCloseable = callable.call()) {
                return function.apply(autoCloseable).get();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                return defaultSupplier.get();
            }
        };
    }

    public static <INPUT, OUTPUT> Function<INPUT, OUTPUT> function(Supplier<OUTPUT> supplier) {
        return i -> supplier.get();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Map<String, Collection<String>> anagrams = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
        int count = tryWithResources(
                () -> new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openStream())),
                reader -> () -> reader.lines().parallel().mapToInt(word -> {
                    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
                    Arrays.parallelSort(chars);
                    String key = Arrays.toString(chars);
                    Collection<String> collection = anagrams.computeIfAbsent(key, function(ArrayList::new));
                    collection.add(word);
                    return collection.size();
                }).max().orElse(0), () -> 0).get();
        anagrams.values().stream().filter(ana -> ana.size() >= count).forEach((list) -> {
            for (String s : list)
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            System.out.println();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I've simplified your example to the core part:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    withCallable(() -> new URL("url").openStream()); // compiles
    withSupplier(() -> new URL("url").openStream()); // does not compile
}

public static <T> void withCallable(Callable<T> callable) { }

public static <T> void withSupplier(Supplier<T> callable) { }
```

If you try with this, you will see that `withCallable` will compile fine but that `withSupplier` does not compile; even if the lambda expression is compatible with the signature of both functional interfaces.

The reason behind this is that the functional method of the [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface, which is [`call()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call--), declares `throws Exception` in its signature. [`Supplier.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--) does not.

Quoting the JLS [section 11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a lambda body can throw some exception class E when E is a checked exception class and E is not a subclass of some class declared in the throws clause of the function type targeted by the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, one could not handle exception thrown in the lambda if the abstract method implemented by the lambda doesn't have throws in its signature.

There's a workaround, known as [sneaky throw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27644392/1362755); here a [simpler example](http://www.jayway.com/2010/01/29/sneaky-throw/) without the functional helpers.

By having a few static helper functions that turn your throwing signatures into non-throwing ones which trick the compiler into rethrowing checked exceptions you can turn

```
.stream().map(x -> {
  try {
    return this.throwingFunction(x)
  } catch(Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}).forEach(...)
```

into

`.stream().map(uncheckedFunc(this::throwingFunction)).forEach(...)`

without wrapping the exception into a generic runtime exception.

Comment: But that's not the question here. This is more a comment.