# Java 8 streams & Formatter or String::format

Tags: java-8, java-stream, formatter

How can I format a string with streams, without using lambda? I've been looking at `Formatter` but can't find any method that would only take a single string... so I could do:

```
Set<String> imported = new HashSet<>();
extendedModels.stream().filter((x)->imported.add(x))
    .map(new Formatter("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n")::format);
```

*I'm just starting with Java 8 so not sure if the above is a right syntax (referencing a method of an object).*

Specifically I look for a way to format the strings without the lambda expression. The reason is brevity - because, the pre-Java 8 form is just:

```
for (String m : extendedModels)
    if (imported.add(m))
        tsWriter.write(String.format("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n", m));
```

#### Details not related to the question:

I'm trying to go through a list of strings, reduce them to unique*) ones, and then use them in an formatted string, which will ultimately written to a `Writer`. Here's what I have now:

This would work but I'd have to handle an `IOException` in `forEach`:

```
extendedModels.stream().filter(imported::add)
.map((x)->{return String.format("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n", x);})
.forEach(tsWriter::write);
```

So for now I use this:

```
tsWriter.write(
    extendedModels.stream()
        .filter(imported::add)
        .map((x)->{return String.format("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n", x);})
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
);
```

*) The uniqueness is across multiple sets, not just the `extendedModels` so I don't want to use some sort of `unique` stream util.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Collect some import statement strings in a list? Output them to a stream?

Comment: Oh, you want to do everything with method references, without lambda expressions?

Comment: Kind of. For brevity and readability. It's doable but I can't find a class for that.

Answer (score 3):

As for avoiding using a lambda expression and using only method references, you need to extract the formatting part to a static or an instance method and reference it using a method reference expression:

```
static String formatImportStatement(String imp) {
    return String.format("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n", imp);
}
```

then `.map(YourClass::formatImportStatement)`. Or you could also extract the labmda itself to a variable like this:

```
Function<String, String> importFormatter = 
    (s) ->  String.format("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n", s);
```

then use it directly: `.map(importFormatter)`.

---

Regarding exceptions:

You can use a delegating `Writer` wrapper which softens (converts checked to unchecked) exceptions and undeclares the checked `IOException`-s from it's method signatures, then use that with `.forEach(softeningWriter::write)`.

You can also use a lambda wrapper factory to wrap your lambda to soften the exceptions like the `LambdaExceptionUtil` class in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27644392/2699901), with the `.forEach(rethrowConsumer(tsWriter::write))` pattern.

And your third solution could also work if you don't mind collecting the import statements to a `String` using `Collectors.joining()` first.

Unfortunately, you need to work around the checked exceptions (at least in Java8 as of today). Maybe a future version of Java will do something about this legacy, but this is not guaranteed to happen as far as I know.

Comment: Ok thanks, but the question is about the formatting - how to avoid the lambda less readable expression and use something like new Formatter("%s...")::format

Comment: Yea, sure, you can use `Formatter` too, but then you need to manually query the formatter for `IOException`-s, because `Formatter` swallows IOExceptions for you.

Comment: `String.format` also “swallows the `IOException`” or did you have to add a `try catch` block?

Comment: @Holger [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) doesn't declare to throw `IOException` so there's no need to catch it.

Comment: So does `Formatter.format`. That’s what your statement “then you need to *manually* query the formatter for `IOException`” implies. For the records, `String.format(String,Object...)` is implemented as `return new Formatter().format(format, args).toString();`. So the question is why the OP should be required to “manually query the formatter” when using the `Formatter` the same way `String.format` does.

Comment: `Formatter` can output to `File`, `OutputStream` or `Appendable`, all of them could throw an `IOException` which `Formatter` will suppress, and you need to explicitly check for that case by querying `Formatter.ioException()` to handle it. `String.format()` will use `Formatter` with a default `StringBuilder` which is an `Appendable` too, but it's guaranteed never to throw an `IOException`. That's a subtle but important difference between the two usage patterns.

Comment: The OP’s suggested use case, `new Formatter("%s...")::format`, if it was valid, isn’t different to what `String.format` does. Actually, the form doesn’t matter, the OP only wants to pre-bind the format string to the construct, be it `String::format` or `new Formatter()::format`. Unfortunately, there is no difference in these two, regarding this intention.

Answer (score 0):

Note that while `.filter(imported::add)` looks like a clever trick, it’s a discouraged technique, as it creates a *stateful predicate*. If all you want, is uniqueness, just use `.distinct()` instead. If you need `imported` later-on, create it with a straight-forward Collection operation, i.e. `imported = new HashSet<>(extendedModels)` and stream over the `Set`.

So if your `Writer` is going to write into a file or any path, there is a `FileSystem` implementation for, a simple solution is

```
Set<String> imported = new HashSet<>(extendedModels);
Files.write(path, () -> imported.stream()
    .<CharSequence>map(x->String.format("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n", x)).iterator());
```

or, if you don’t need the `imported` Set later-on:

```
Files.write(path, () -> extendedModels.stream().distinct()
    .<CharSequence>map(x->String.format("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n", x)).iterator());
```

If there is no `Path`, i.e. you can’t avoid using a predefined `Writer`, you can use a `Formatter`, but have to care about not missing an exception:

```
Formatter f=new Formatter(tsWriter);
extendedModels.stream().distinct().forEachOrdered(
    x -> f.format("import {%1$s} from './%1$s';\n", x));
f.flush();
if(f.ioException()!=null) throw f.ioException();
```

There is no way to provide a bound parameter to a method reference, but since the tokens `String`, `format` and the string literal are unavoidable, there is not much potential saving anyway.