# Why can't we throw exception inside Java 8 stream?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

E.g:

```
Person result = persons.stream()
                  .filter(x -> {
                    if ("test".equals(x.getName() ) ) {
                      throw new IOException("not possible inside stream y ?"); //any checked exception
                    }
                    //code here
                  })
```

M looking for reason why it is not being allowed ? Even if method in which code is declared throws IOException

Comment: What is the error that you get? Maybe a missing return statement? I think this should be possible.

Comment: The lambda's gotta return a `boolean`.  Other than that you are good.

Comment: Sorry updated my question. I am unable to throw checked exception even if it is declared as throws in method signature or whole expression is under try/catch.... Looking for reason why ? Or if there r ways which we can do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I throw CHECKED exceptions from inside Java 8 streams?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644361/how-can-i-throw-checked-exceptions-from-inside-java-8-streams)

Comment: Thanks @Federico. So its a bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code is working perfectly, apart from a missing semi colon at the end of the `throw new ...` line, and from a missing a return statement that may be hidden in `// code here`.

What you can't do is throw a checked exception (which RuntimeException is not) because checked exception are part of the method signature and the Predicate.test method do not declare one.

EDIT :
To see more precisely what is happening and why you can't throw a checked exception here, here is how you could have written the code without lambda :

From this :

```
public Person myMethod() throws IOException {
    Person result = persons.stream()
              .filter(x -> {
                if ("test".equals(x.getName() ) ) {
                  throw new IOException("not possible inside stream y ?"); //any checked exception
                }
                //code here
                return true;
              });
    return person;
}
```

to this :

```
public Person myMethod() throws IOException {
    Person result = persons.stream()
              .filter(new Predicate<Person>() {
                  public boolean test(Person x) {
                      if ("test".equals(x.getName() ) ) {
                          throw new IOException("not possible inside stream y ?"); //any checked exception
                      }
                      //code here
                      return true;
                  }
              });
    return person;
}
```

As you can see, the code inside the lambda expression is now inside the `test` method of an anonymous `Predicate` class, which is not declaring any checked exception.

Why `Predicate` ? Because it is what the `filter` method is expecting, and you can use a lambda instead of a conventional object because it is a single method interface : only `test` is abstract, and your lambda signature should be the same as the `Predicate.test` method.

If you really wish to be able to handle checked exceptions, the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644361/how-can-i-throw-checked-exceptions-from-inside-java-8-streams?noredirect=1&lq=1) (in a comment from Frederico) show some ways to bypass these limitations.

Comment: Sorry updated my question. I am unable to throw checked exception even if it is declared as throws in method signature or whole expression is under try/catch.... Looking for reason why ? Or if there r ways which we can do it.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that the lambda expression is inside the `test` method—that’s too misleading. The lambda expression is inside `myMethod`, but it has to fulfill the signature constraints of the `test` method.

Comment: @Holger : i didn't mean the lambda expression, but the code inside the lambda. I'll edit to clarify this.

Comment: I know what you mean, but the code of the lambda expression isn’t inside the `test` method; code inside the `test` method can access inherited members of the `Predicate` interface and within the `test` method, `this` refers to the `Predicate` instance. Neither applies to the code of the lambda expression, it can’t access `Predicate` members and `this` refers to the owner of `myMethod()`. Also the accessibility rules are different. The only relationship to the `test` method is the requirement to fulfill its signature contract.

Comment: Good points about the accessibility rules. I'll edit further to remove the wrong parts

Answer (score 5):

> looking for reason why it is not being allowed ?

You are implementing a `Predicate` which doesn't declare a checked Exception.

Exceptions are side effects and no favoured by functional designers and most likely this is the reason they are not supported very well.

I use a trick to pass the checked exception out and catch it later. Another option is to wrap it with an unchecked exception or use a class like `IORuntimeException` In different cases I use all three options.

https://vanilla-java.github.io/2016/06/21/Reviewing-Exception-Handling.html