# java "throws" clause not working

Tags: java, exception

Why does the following code snippet

```
private void getEvents() throws VersionNotFoundException{
    gameRepository.findAll().forEach(game->{
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String appVersion = getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
        if (appVersion==null) {
            throw new VersionNotFoundException();
        }
        headers.set("X-TBA-App-Id","4205:"+this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion());
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        restTemplate.exchange(getEventsForYearString, HttpMethod.GET,requestEntity , Event.class, game.getYear());
    });
}

private class VersionNotFoundException extends Exception {
}
```

in a class cause the line `throw new VersionNotFoundException();` to raise a compiler error that `VersionNotFoundException` `must be caught or declared to be thrown`? It very clearly is declared to be thrown.

Comment: You should define throws for the lambda function

Comment: And also you should follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @LewBloch Can you elaborate? The majority of java naming conventions I have seen would consider this compliant.

Comment: You have `AppVersion` as a variable name; as such it should begin with a lower-case letter. As spelled it looks like a type name.

Comment: @LewBloch fixed. It was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the lambda method you're overriding doesn't have `VersionNotFoundException` in its signature, so overridden methods can't either (including your lambda). Since `#forEach` accepts a consumer which doesn't allow checked exceptions, you always have to catch exceptions in that lambda.

As for determining if you need to throw an exception, I would do that outside of the `#forEach` entirely:

```
private void getEvents() throws VersionNotFoundException {
    String appVersion = getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    if (appVersion == null) {
        throw new VersionNotFoundException();
    }
    gameRepository.findAll().forEach(game-> {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("X-TBA-App-Id", "4205:"+ appVersion);
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        restTemplate.exchange(getEventsForYearString, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Event.class, game.getYear());
    });
}
```

Comment: I had forgotten that I was working in a foreach. After I noticed, I ended up changing it to more-or-less what you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

The lambda function passed to `gameRepository.findAll().forEach()` doesn't have `throws`. That's what the error is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Checked Exceptions cannot be thrown in lambda expressions. The fact that this was inside a lambda slipped my mind.

Comment: Well they can, the receiving method has to accept a functional interface which allows a checked exception

Comment: @Rogue I had found a stackoverflow answer I that said It couldn't be done. Has that changed since then? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27668305/4160312

Comment: You can specify your own functional interfaces, and utilize those for methods. However this isn't wholly stream-compatible