# How do I return a value from a lambda within the method I want to return on?

Tags: java, lambda, return

How do I return a value from a lambda within the method I want to return on?

Originally, I had this:

```
myCollection.forEach(item -> {
  try {
    doSomething(item);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return "There was a problem doing something: " + e.getMessage();
  }
});
```

But my intent was to return on the method *containing* all this code, not return on just the lambda. So, I ended up having to do this:

```
String error = "";
myCollection.stream().filter(item -> {
  try {
    doSomething(item);
    return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    error = "There was a problem doing something: " + e.getMessage();
  }
  return false;
});
if (!error.isEmpty()) {
  return error;
}
```

But this can't be the best way. What's the Java 8 functional, elegant way to do this?

Comment: What is it you're really trying to do?

Comment: Do you use filtered stream after that?
BTW you can't assign a value from lambda expression to external variable:
`error = "There was a problem doing something: " + e.getMessage();`

Comment: Given a collection of Strings (URLs), I need to run each through a third party URL verifier. Unfortunately this verifier only raises errors by throwing an exception (as opposed to returning `false` with a retrievable error message). Given an exception, I need to return a javaslang `Validation.invalid(e.getMessage())`.

Comment: Your _I ended up having to do this_ cannot be true. `filter` is not a terminal operation and assigning a value to a captured variable is not allowed. Please post realistic code and explain what you think is wrong with it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I mean, the first example never worked to begin with. I meant to say, "This was the best I could come up with." But you're right, I should have added a `findFirst()` to terminate that line. In any case, the bigger problem was: returning on wrong level.

Comment: I think you should consider not to use a lambda for the job. In this case a "for-each" `for` on the collection would be more appropriate. Is the case what you are presenting is a distilled version of your actual code and that you really need to use a lambda here? If not, use a "for-each" `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use a Lambda here? The best Java way would be just use 1.5 for-each on the collection:

```
try {
  for (final E item : myCollection) {
     doSomething(item)
  }
} catch (final Exception ex) {
  return "blah";
}
```

Notice that one pays a performance penalty when entering and exiting the `try-catch` block so is better to have it outside the loop.

Comment: Checked exceptions apparently make my situation very difficult. So this is what I ended up doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Anything thrown from inside of the stream can be caught with a `try` clause surrounding the stream.

```
try {
    myCollection.forEach(SurroundingClass::doSomething);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return "..."
}
```

However, I do not recommend using exceptions as a way of flow control. Throwing and catching exceptions are slow. You should always check whether your data will produce an exception or not before passing it to `doSomething` if you can.

If you are talking about checked exceptions, there is no easy way to handle them. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644361/how-can-i-throw-checked-exceptions-from-inside-java-8-streams) if you want to know about some (pretty lengthy) workarounds.

Comment: I agree, it's not the ideal way I wish to go. But unfortunately I don't have control over `doSomething()` as it's provided by a third party. I didn't know exceptions can be handled outside! Thank you.

Comment: Exceptions _can't_ be handled outside like this with normal streams.  This doesn't work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman This is not a stream. See this: https://ideone.com/NsXqKX

Comment: Hm, I don't know how to formulate my code like this. I simplified a part out thinking nothing of it. I'm actually acting on `item.url()` for each `item`, so I don't think I can pass in a method reference alone...

Comment: @AndrewCheong you can then `map` each item and then `forEach` it.

Comment: Thank you, but actually now it's still complaining that the exception is not handled... The highlighted segment is `SurroundingClass::doSomething`; says its exception isn't being handled.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Oh so the exception is checked! You didn't say that in the question so I was confused. If that's the case, you can only do it the way you do it now, unfortunately...

Comment: I'm coming from 10 years of C++ haha... this is my first time hearing about "checked" exceptions. Man, do I have a long way to go... thank you all for your help. If you edit your answer to say, given checked exceptions, my way is the only way, then I will accept it.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644361/how-can-i-throw-checked-exceptions-from-inside-java-8-streams it shows some not-quite-elegant ways to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, I haven't tested.

```
   myCollection.stream().map(item -> {
      try {
        doSomething(item);
        return null;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        return "There was a problem doing something: " + e.getMessage();
      }
    }).filter(exp -> exp!=null).findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling of checked exceptions in lambdas can be achieved in following way

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Exception> {
        void accept(T t) throws E;
    }

    private static <T> Consumer<T> wrap(ThrowingConsumer<T, Exception> throwingConsumer) {
        return item -> {
            try {
                throwingConsumer.accept(item);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        };
    }

    private String processCollection(List</* whatever type */> myCollection) {
        try {
            myCollection.forEach(wrap(this::doSomething));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage(); // error
        }
        return null; // no error
    }
```