# How do we handle exception in java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I convert this for loop using the stream.

```
for (final Foo foo : fooList) {
    if (!FooConstant.FOO_TYPE.equals(foo.getType())) {
        throw new BadRequestException(
          LOGGER,
          FooErrorEnum.NOT_FOO_TYPE.name(),
          String.format("Element %s is not Foo type", foo.getId())
        );
    }
}
```

I tried doing this way but the `foo.getId()` is not available in `orElseThrow()`.
Note: BadRequestException is checked exception.

```
fooList.stream().filter(foo -> !FooConstant.FOO_TYPE.equals(foo.getType())
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException(LOGGER, FooErrorEnum.NOT_FOO_TYPE.name(), String.format("Element %s is not Foo type", foo.getId()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`Optional#ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)).

```
fooList.stream().filter(foo -> !FooConstant.FOO_TYPE.equals(foo.getType())
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(foo -> {
                     throw new BadRequestException(LOGGER, FooErrorEnum.NOT_FOO_TYPE.name(), String.format("Element %s is not Foo type", foo.getId())
                });
```

It's weird, though. We usually use `Optional` the other way around: to filter out invalid options and find the first valid one. In your example, `orElseThrow` would be executed when everything is fine, so no exception should be thrown.

Note that `BadRequestException` must be a `RuntimeException`, otherwise [it won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception).

Comment: What if its checked exception? How do we use orElseThrow?

Comment: @Deepak you can't throw a checked exception from either `ifPresent` or `orElseThrow`. Read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644361/how-can-i-throw-checked-exceptions-from-inside-java-8-streams

Comment: So in this case I can only use for loop ?

Comment: @Deepak yes (if you want to throw a checked exception from `ifPresent`). You could throw an unchecked exception from the lambda, intercept it by a try-catch block surrounding `fooList.stream()` and rethrow a checked one, but it's too much. A simple loop is always better.