# Java 8 use throws functions instead of try catch

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to apply a function to a list of value, if in this function the value match, It returns an MyExceptions(a custom kind of Exceptions).
I a use a single value like this:

```
myFunctions.checkValue(myValue);
```

I can throws MyExceptions directly in my function declaration, but if I have a list of value, I can't use the throws but I have to use try/catch. Like this:

```
public void firstCheckValue(String value1,List<String> listValue) throws MyException{
        myFunctions.checkValue(value1);
        listValue.stream().forEach(p->{
        try {
            listValue.checkValue(p);
        } catch (MyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Why I can't use :

```
listValue.stream().forEach(p->myFunctions.checkValue(p));
```

And directly throws MyExceptions?

Comment: Is this your IDE (Intellij) telling you that you can't use "Throws" or is the compiler giving you the error directly?

Comment: Because `forEach` accepts a `Consumer` argument and the `Consumer#accept` method is not capable of throwing checked exceptions.

Comment: Also, if the sole operation on your stream is `forEach` then there's no reason to create a stream; just use `listValue.forEach(...)` directly (the method is inherited from `Iterable`). It'd be even better to simply use an enhanced for loop (e.g. `for (String p : listValue) { checkValue(p); }` as then you could throw your checked exception.

Comment: @Slaw so there is not a "stream" approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RuntimeException class as the parent of MyException

Comment: I can't, MyException is in a standard library that I have implemented and it is used by other project

Comment: In that case, move this code to a new method. Inside catch block write `throw new RuntimeException(e);` With this, you can wrap you checked exception to unchecked one. Anytime you can get your original exception with the `getCause()` method of RuntimeException

Comment: My MyExceptions class it's already extending a class, Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a similar question [How can I throw CHECKED exceptions from inside Java 8 streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644361/how-can-i-throw-checked-exceptions-from-inside-java-8-streams).

I think the best way is https://github.com/ahmedbaberkhan/Utility/commit/5e62034fde4b46957cca1688be856dcebd61539d.