# Why am I not able to use throws IOException in my method which uses toRealPath(), instead I have to use try catch?

Tags: java, exception, path, nio, ioexception

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Rose {

    public void tendGarden(Path p) throws IOException {
        Files.walk(p,1)
                .map(q -> q.toRealPath())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] thorns) throws IOException {
        new Rose().tendGarden(Paths.get(thorns[0]));
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't compile because of q.toRealPath(), instead throws java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. while I am already throwing it to main method which is throwing it to java environment. Somewhere I read that because of using interface as a method signature I am not able to use throws. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: The problem is that the functional interface used by `map` doesn't allow you to throw checked exceptions, so you must handle them in the lambda. That said, I don't even think it is necessary to call `toRealPath` here.

Comment: I was just exploring on how to throw a checked exception for lambda expression, turns out that java doesn't support throws for checked exceptions in lambdas/stream instead I have to use try, catch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644361/how-can-i-throw-checked-exceptions-from-inside-java-8-lambdas-streams

Comment: will be closing the question as the functionality is not available from java side

Comment: Lambdas do support it, but only if the abstract method of the functional interface has a suitable `throws` clause, and the functional interfaces defined in Java itself don't do that. You would have to define your own functional interfaces to be able to do that, which means you can only use them with your own APIs, and not the ones defined in Java itself. As an aside: your question is already closed, and there is no need to delete it: it can serve as a signpost for other people searching for the same problem.