# Handled Java Exception resulting in Unhandled Exception

Tags: java

```
public List<OpBase> getHistory(ESRequest historyRequest)
        throws IOException, ResourceNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
    String url = baseUrl + opIndex + "/_search";
    String resp = makeESQuery(historyRequest, url);
    HistoryResponse historyResponse = objectMapper.readValue(resp, HistoryResponse.class);
    List<OpBase> returnMsgList = new ArrayList<>();
    historyResponse.tasks.tasks.forEach(editTaskMsgResponse -> {
            Map<String, Object> msgObject = editTaskMsgResponse.source.msg;
            String taskType = (String) msgObject.get("task_type");
            EditTaskType editTaskType = EditTaskType.valueOf(taskType);
            switch(editTaskType) {
                case MIGRATE_PLACE: returnMsgList.add(objectMapper.readValue(
                        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msgObject), MatchingTaskOperatorMetricsMsg.class));
                case CURATE_PLACE:
                case QC_PLACE: returnMsgList.add(objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msgObject),
                        MatchingTaskOperatorMetricsMsg.class));
            }
        });
    return returnMsgList;
}
```

I get an unhandled IOException exception error with lines like `objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msgObject),
                            MatchingTaskOperatorMetricsMsg.class));`

But I am explicitly saying this method throws this exception?

Comment: Does `forEach` throw exceptions? Maybe have a look at [How do I work with exception throwing methods in streams?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548589/java-8-how-do-i-work-with-exception-throwing-methods-in-streams)

Comment: Are you sure you saved and recompiled your code?  Throwing `IOException` should have made this go away.

Comment: You can say your code throws this exception.  But if nothing up the stack handles the exception, the program will still blow up.

Comment: @MadProgrammer ah yeah that was it! i'm new to java8, thanks for your help!

Comment: @ShailPatel Yea for wild guessing :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning might be showing withing the lines that's wrapped inside `switch-case` statements. The one that's outside it would be working fine.

The reason is because that code is inside `lambda` expression. Unhandled exceptions aren't handled this way in streams and lambda expressions.

You would have to wrap the code written inside `lambda` expression in `try-catch`

```
historyResponse.tasks.tasks.forEach(editTaskMsgResponse -> {
            Map<String, Object> msgObject = editTaskMsgResponse.source.msg;
            String taskType = (String) msgObject.get("task_type");
            EditTaskType editTaskType = EditTaskType.valueOf(taskType);
            switch(editTaskType) {
                case MIGRATE_PLACE: 
                    try {
                        returnMsgList.add(objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msgObject), MatchingTaskOperatorMetricsMsg.class));
                    }
                    catch(IOException io) {}
                case CURATE_PLACE:
                case QC_PLACE: 
                    try {
                        returnMsgList.add(objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msgObject), MatchingTaskOperatorMetricsMsg.class));
                    }
                    catch(IOException io) {}
            }
        });
```

See also:

1. [Java 8 method reference unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25643348/2815219)
2. [Java 8: How do I work with exception throwing methods in streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23548589/2815219)