# Exceptions in java lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, stream

I have this code:

```
private void save(List<String> items) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
            for (String item : items) {
                fileWriter.write(item);
            }

            // Error for: "Unhandled exception: java.io.Exception"
            items.stream().forEach(fileWriter::write);
        }
    }
```

It should write each element from the list passed to file.

I'm learning java streams and wanted to write each element with *forEach* function but run into strange error. Even my function **throws IOException** my IDE and compiled still complains about uncaught exception.

Do you need to catch it in lambda itself? Can it be thrown to parent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I throw an exception in a Java 8 lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726874/why-cant-i-throw-an-exception-in-a-java-8-lambda-expression) and [Java 8 method reference unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643348/java-8-method-reference-unhandled-exception).

Comment: See dupe, but that’s the deal with lambdas - they can’t throw checked exceptions.